# Почему у спрайтов одного разрешения, разное положение по Y

Tags: unity3d, анимация, спрайт

[Idle спрайт](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmnHI.png)

[Run спрайт](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeR9t.png)

Это приводит к тому что при анимации бездействия, персонаж "парит" в воздухе, у всех спрайтов разрешение 100х55

Comment: Pivot point разный

Comment: Как фиксить ? через редактор ? или средствами Unity можно ?

Comment: Всё, разобрался, огромное спасибо